# centering a div inside of a div with background-size: cover property

Tags: css, html, resize, center

I want to center an image on top of my background image.

#home is the background image that stretches to the size of the browser
 #hometitle is the image i want on top

**I would like to center #hometitle on top of my #home background so no matter the size of the browser, it'll be spaced into the center of the background image.**

I have tried margin: 0 auto; and then margin-top: 250px; right after, but that just creates a white gap above the entire background image of 250px;

Position: absolute; and top/left don't really help because the position will be static and not be center as you resize the browser.

```
#home {
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-image: url("images/bigheader.png");
}

#hometitle {
background-image:url(images/title.png);
height: 260px;
width: 435px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="home">
    <div id="hometitle">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#hometitle {
    background-image:url(images/title.png);
    height: 260px;
    width: 435px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -130px;
    margin-left: -217px;
}
```

This should do since we postion the home title image absolutely at the center of the browser rendering space.
If you are having some issues with the position of image add

```
body {position: relative;}
```

This is one of the easiest and best techniques to position an element at the center that i use often

Comment: Thank you, it works! how did you know to include margin-top: -130px;
and margin-left: -217px; ?

Comment: Also, what if I would like something center but right below my #hometitle?

Comment: it depends on the width and height of the div. you have to pull it half to the top and half to the left

Comment: Also, what if I would like something center but right below my #hometitle?--- Play with the top value of the div. you'll find a value that aligns it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `margin-top` to move the `<div id="hometitle">` down relative to the `<div id="home">` because of margin collapsing, but you could add top padding on the `<div id="home">` instead.